# Can I re-assign an office in prison architect?

Tags: prison-architect

Staff automatically choose their office (I think they choose the oldest existing office room) when I hire them.

Can I assign them to the office I want?

This would be useful to put staff near places they need to be (Foreman near workshop for example)

I have tried to hire them in a specific office but they directly move.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that they claim the oldest office first, and this appears to be the only way to assign them.  The [Wiki](http://prison-architect.wikia.com/wiki/Office) recommends:

> If multiple unclaimed offices exist when a new staff member is hired, they will claim the office which was created first.  To force a staff member to claim a certain office, de-zone all other offices before or after hiring them.